# Adding a plugin link for "a plugin is needed to display this content"

Tags: firefox, plugins, embed, vlc

I'm embedding VLC in to a webpage, I want the user to be prompted to download VLC if it isn't already installed. I'm using Firefox to test with, if VLC isn't installed it shows a grey box with the text "a plugin is needed to display this content", is it possible to add a download link to this window?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you are using the "embed" tag to define a plugin in a html page, which allows the inclusion of the optional argument "pluginspage", which you should set to our website (aka "http://www.videolan.org/vlc/") like in our sample code for the web plugin.

Alternatively, you could set "pluginurl" for the direct download link, but given that this would be different URLs for different operating systems, the argument above is the proper way.

Regrettably, I can't say if this argument is actually respected by Firefox, but it should be.